# how to reapply the same certificate to my JDK?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keystore

I created a jetty.crt and imported that to my JDK security cert as follows:

```
sudo /usr/java/latest/bin/keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias jetty -file /path/etc/jetty.crt -keystore  /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/security/cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

I realized that I wanted to re-create the certificate. But when importing the certificate again using the same command above, it doesn't accept it. I was forced to create another certificate with another alias and then import it. Is there any way i can import with the same alias again?

Note: I do not want to delete the previous import.

Update: The error I get when reapplying the same alias is :
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias  already exists java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias  already exists at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.addTrustedCert(KeyTool.java:1903) at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:818) at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172) at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166) –

Thanks

Comment: *"when importing the certificate again using the same command above, it doesn't accept it."* - what was the error?

Comment: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <jetty> already exists
java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <jetty> already exists
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.addTrustedCert(KeyTool.java:1903)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:818)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)

Comment: Please revisit your question, click *Edit*, and add the information to the question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in Stack Overflow's Help Center.